# Generation of pseudorandom floating point numbers on floating point vector DSP

Tags: pseudo-random-generators

I am working on a custom IEEE754 floating point vector signal processor with 64 cores and need to generate pseudo-random floating point numbers at high rate. The only numerical operation available to me is a vector wide floating point multiply-add. I cannot therefore use any of the conventional algorithms based on feedback shift registers, linear congruential operations etc. I cannot do any vector integer or bitwise operations... just a 32 bit IEEE754 vector floating point MAC on all 64 cores.

The only approach I have found that maps to the architecture is an iterated chaotic logistic map and related variants but I don't like these since they inevitably converge to a stable fixed point. They do have the advantage, however, of returning 64 pseudo-random numbers every clock cycle. Can anyone offer suggestions for a better algorithm suited to the architecture?

Comment: What are your seed values? You need seeds if you don't want to generate the same "random" numbers on all 64 cores. Do you start with 64 different floating point seeds for the 64 cores? If so, what are the ranges of these seed values?

Comment: Also, does your processor implement IEEE 754-compliant handling of denormal numbers? If so, you might be able to fake integer operations by abusing denormal arithmetic to compute in the significand bits.

Comment: If what you say is true, you are screwed. If you only have multiplication and addition no matter what algorithm you apply, it will always just be a polynomial expression with the seed(s) as variable(s) and will not be suitable as noise for most applications.

Comment: @orlp First, polynomial iterates can be chaotic, e.g. the logistic map example mentioned in the question. Second, floating point numbers are not real numbers, e.g. the denormal arithmetic I mentioned.

Comment: The quadratic map is xn=4.0F*xn*(1.0F-xn) and generates pseudo-random numbers in the range 0 to 1. Each of the 64 cores is initialized with a different seed. There is a fair amount of literature about using this mapping but I don't like it for the reasons I mentioned. I'm sure there must be variants that are superior.

Comment: IBM developed an implementation of the linear congruential method delivering 53 bits using fused multiply/add that ran on a POWER processor with 1 cycle throughput. A paper about that would be more than 20 years old. (One cycle).

Comment: Probably irrelevant due to my ignorance, but: (1) An LCG is just a multiply and an add plus a modulo operation.  What happens when you overflow a register?  Can it be set to implement mod 2^53 or something similar on overflow?  I know you're working with floats, but at bottom they're just 53 bit-sequences, right? (2) LCG's aren't ideal, but with more bits they're not so bad, and [O'Neill's PCG prng](http://www.pcg-random.org) algorithms combine multiple LCGs with different parameters to get better randomness; maybe you could run multiple LCGs in parallel and then combine them similarly?